# Leading two digits of a four digit perfect square.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The number $19$ has the following properties:

$1)$ It is a two digit number.

$2)$ It is the leading two digits of a four digit perfect square $44^2 = 1936$

How many number are there that satisfy the same property?

---

Note that we have four digit perfect square from $32^2$ to $99^2$.

Let the number be $(10a+b)^2$. Then we have $100a^2 +20ab + b^2$.

Here $a \ge 3$.

When $a = 3$, we have $900+60b+b^2$, thus all numbers from $10-15$ occurs as the leading 2 digits.

---

I have tried with brute force to find the numbers.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Call the property P.

Step 1:
For $32^2$ -> 10 to $49^2$ -> 24

You should show all numbers st $10 \leq n \leq 24$ have the property P.

So there are 15 numbers.

Step 2:
For $50^2$ -> 25 to $99^2$ -> 98
You should show each perfect square will give a distinct number with property P.

So there are 50 numbers.

Then you can count there are 65 numbers with property P.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose two squares had the same two first digits. You would have to have $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)\lt 100$ for a start, and that reduces the number of options. For example, you would have to have $a=b+1$ because $a+b\gt 50$ and also $b\lt 50$ else $a+b\gt 100$.

That reduces the number of cases and I am sure you can deal with the numbers in the $40$s as efficiently as you have done with the numbers in the $30$s.